# Add image underneath cursor on hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover, cursor

I'm trying to attach an image to the cursor when you hover an other image (or div for that matter..). I would like to let the image move with the cursor and disappear again when the cursor leaves the div.

I tried changing the cursor with css `cursor: url(images/my-cursor.png), auto;`. But that didn't work for me.

Is there a way to make an image stick to the cursor on hover? And if so, how would I implement this in my code?

Hope someone can help, thanks!

Comment: take away the auto and just leave your url(your cursor). the auto sets the default cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
cursor:url("images/my-cursor.png"),default;
```

Not sure whether it will work in your case